# How to use has_many fields in views, rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, has-many

Frnds I am new to rails, here i created two tables caleed stocks and stock_availabilities.

in the stock model

```
class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :projects_lkp

  has_many :stock_availabilities

  validates_presence_of :item

end
```

In the stock_availabilities model

```
class StockAvailability < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :stock

  validates_presence_of :qty,:add_or_issue,:price, :captured_at, :stock_id,:unit

end
```

Now my doubt is how to bring the field of stock_availabilties in the views of stock

```
<% @stock.each do |d|  %>  
  <tr>
  <td><%= d.item %></td>

  "Here i need to print the values of qty and pricevwhich is in stock_availabilities class"? 

  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

this is what you need:

```
<% @stock.each do |d|  %>  
  <tr>
  <td><%= d.item %></td>

  <% d.stock_availabilities.each do |sAV|  %>  
   <td> <%= sAV.qty %> </td>
       ...  <-- You do the other ones here
  <% end %>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Thanq (Y)! @The Fabio